# Unable to change Product Name in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, crash, xcode4.6

I am developing for iOS 6 on Xcode 4.6.1

Midway through my project I decided to change name of both the project as well as the app name.

Changing the project name was pretty straightforward. As mentioned by many, I am supposed to

> Double click slowly on the Xcode Project name on the top left. Change this name and a window will pop up asking you to rename the whole project, select yes and the name of your project  will be changed.

But I noticed that my app target did not change.

So I tried to manually rename it. When I change my app target and run the app, it crashes.

This is the log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

I went through my code and found out that this line was causing the error:

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 pathForResource:videoName
                 ofType:@"mp4"];
```

The `url` has the value `nil`.

If I revert the target name back to the original, it works.

I tried a project build clean. I also tried resetting and cleaning the simulator. Nothing seems to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can try check in "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources" list your file which name is in videoName with .mp4?

Comment: You tried clean from Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> Your project -> Delete...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your mp4 file in "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources" list and then press "Delete..." on  Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> Your project.

Comment: Hi. Just checked. my mp4 file wasn't there. I added it and now it seems to be working fine. But I have a feeling I broke a lot of things while doing it. Because a lot of files aren't appearing in "Copy Bundle Resources"

Any idea how to avoid this? Or how to fix everything? I guess many references are still broken.

Comment: Guess I'll just create a new project and transfer my code. Just to be safe.

Comment: You can remove all resources and add they again.

Comment: Yes, I cleaned up everything and now it works great. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you  double click and rename, it would have shown an alert, read carefully and check that all options are selected.

[image]